# Multiple Autocomplete Not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }
    $( "#names" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('update/suggestions'); ?>",
            data: { term: extractLast( request.term )},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( "," );
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
    });
});
```

The above code is replacing the existing selection rather than adding the new selection to the existing one. This is in Codeigniter. The single Autocomplete is working fine.
This is not for multiple input fields it is for adding multiple values to a single input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has several issues:

- you are not correctly closing the `$.ajax` function and `source` option function.
- the `minLength: 2` is also misplaced.
- because of previous problems, you got too much closing brackets/parenthesis.

For instance you have:

```
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('update/suggestions'); ?>",
        ...
        success: function(data){
            response(data);
        },
    // missing closings
    focus: function() {
```

which should be:

```
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('update/suggestions'); ?>",
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });   // closes $.ajax function
    },    // closes the 'source' function
    focus: function() {
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/7aGFq/)** with correct syntax. It works correctly (I've added an error handler to the ajax to display some static results).

Comment: This was because I did not filter the list in the error handler (my static data source). I've updated the fiddle and now it is filtering correctly.

Comment: You are a life saver cant thank enough , Been fighting with this for 10 days .

Answer (score 0):

for multiple auto comple , how you are givin the id "#names"?
Did you give same id for all autocomplete input fields .

Try to give a common class for all autocomplete input fields then call like below

```
 $( ".autoclass" ).autocomplete({
```

Comment: That is not for multiple input fields it is for adding multiple values to a single input field.